# Check whether the allow anonymous is on or not in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need a way to check if "allow anonymous" is on/off in the controller action. Whether it comes from controller attribute, action attribute

> [AllowAnonymous]

or it is set as filter in the MvcOptions

> opts.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());

Is it possible?

Comment: This feels like you're trying to do something else, maybe it is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I have one API endpoint, that has to secure images. So you have one time use token, that you need to pass as query, because of browsers. For this one endpoint implementation of custom authenticator would be too much I think. On the other hand for end to end tests and dev purposes I need to tell if it should authenticate.

Answer (score 36):

It seems you need to check whether a controller and action does contain `AllowAnonymousAttribute` from your custom authentication filter during a request. So you can do this as follows:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));
        }

        bool hasAllowAnonymous = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata
                                 .Any(em => em.GetType() == typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute)); //< -- Here it is

        if (hasAllowAnonymous) return;

        // Do your authorization check here
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if AllowAnonymousFilter is set in MvcOptions, at least for dotnet core 3.1. Scan through filterContext.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors will do the work.

Comment: I have the issue that my controller allows anonymous, but my method uses the authorize attribute. Any allows it even though it should not. How can I see what attributes relate to the controller and what relates to the method?

Comment: Is it possible to check this within custom `AuthenticationHandler`? We have a custom authentication handler and running into an issue with Anonymous routes

Answer (score 2):

For checking, whether a controller and action has AllowAnonymous attribute, then in your custom authorization filter you can do this as follows:

For method level allow anonymous attribute:

```
bool hasAllowAnonymous = = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata
                             .Any(em => em.GetType() == typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute));
```

For controller level allow anonymous attribute:

```
bool hasAllowAnonymous = = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.EndpointMetadata
                             .Any(em => em.GetType() == typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute));
```

And then

```
if (hasAllowAnonymous) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the extra info in your comment. This appears to work the same way you should do a password reset.

For a password reset you include a one-time password reset token in the request (along with the password/verified password etc.) I would explicitly decorate the action with `[AllowAnonymous]` and validate the token in the before updating any details and cancelling the token.

In your case, I would do the same thing - explicitly decorate the action with `[AllowAnonymous]` and validate the one-time token. Your action shouldn't care whether the `AllowAnonymous` filter has been applied to the Action via the attribute or options.

**UPDATE**
Been thinking a bit more and there's an easy way to disable this based on the build configuration. Wrap the attribute in an `#if` [preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) and create a build configuration that defines a conditional compliation symbol. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10120360/592958) for details

```cs
#if DISABLE_ALLOW_ANONYOMOUS
    [AllowAnonymous]
#endif
    public IActionResult GetPicture(string token){
        ...
```

You can then build a test specific version where `AllowAnonymous` is disabled.

You could also do the same with MvcOptions:

```cs
#if DISABLE_ALLOW_ANONYOMOUS
    opts.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
#endif
```

Comment: This is my current state actually. But I want to be able to turn off, 
by AllowAnonymousFilter. 

for example my controller action would start like this.

if (!IsAnonymousAllowed) 
   await _authenticationService.AuthorizeFileAsync(accessToken, requestedObject, requestedFilename);

Comment: Why do you want to be able to turn it off?

Comment: Sounds a bit fishy, if you are turning it off, then you're not testing the code/paths through the code that exist in the production environment. Seems to me that doing so would invalidate the test.

Comment: Also, I would have thought that leaving it enabled would actually be the easier - no need to check user credentials and no need for all the data that doing so requires.

Comment: Might also be a good idea to edit the original question with all this extra info.

Comment: The project is really large with a lot of micro-services and pretty large team. There are lots of tests, and of coarse authentication is covered. But for some internal reasons some of tests can't be.
That's great idea, I will edit it in few minutes.

Comment: Thought of another way to do what you're asking, check the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var anonActionAttributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);

        var anonControllerAttributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);

        if (anonActionAttributes.Length > 0 || anonControllerAttributes.Length > 0)            
            IsAllowAnonymous = true;

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    bool IsAllowAnonymous { get; set; } = false;    
}
```

*If you found this answer helpful, kindly upvote it.*

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if the [AllowAnonymous] attribute is used on a WebAPI2 controller action, when using an ActionFilterAttribute this should work

```
public class SomeCheckFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
 {
   public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
      bool hasAllowAnonymous = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute)).Any();
      if (hasAllowAnonymous == false)                                             
       {
        // if NOT Anonymous, do the Filtercheck  
        ...    
       }
    }
 }
```